# Apache proxy - SSLCACertificateFile Directive doesn't work

Tags: apache, ssl

I'm trying to access a url that has a self-signed certificate through apache2 proxy server. (`Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)`). When I do this I get an error

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate

as expected. So to access it I'm trying to add trusted certificates to the server, as per the instructions [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile).

I put this directive in `proxy.conf` and it points to a file that includes the server's certificate, but this has no effect.

I restarted the server (`sudo service apache2 restart`), and did some sanity checks to make sure I'm chaning the correct file. What am I doing wrong?

this is my conf file:

```
listen 8080

SSLProxyCACertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/ca-certificates.crt"

ProxyRequests on
<Proxy "*">
  Require all granted
</Proxy>
```

content of `/usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/ca-certificates.crt`:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFgzCCA2ugAwIBAgIPXZONMGc2yAYdGsdUhGkHMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMDsx
...
RqEIr9baRRmW1FMdW4R58MD3R++Lj8UGrp1MYp3/RgT408m2ECVAdf4WqslKYIYv
uu8wd+RU4riEmViAqhOLUTpPSPaLtrM=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFgzCCA2ugAwIBAgIPXZONMGc2yAYdGsdUhGkHMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMDsx
...
uu8wd+RU4riEmViAqhOLUTpPSPaLtrM=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SSLProxyCACertificateFile`, not `SSLProxyCACertificatePath`?

Comment: @DusanBajic yes, thanks. it was a mistake in the question, I tried both

Comment: Try accessing the url with `curl -v --cacert <file>` from apache machine, it might give more descriptive error

Comment: @DusanBajic with curl the request works